# Why does this fragment of text render differently in a browser?

Tags: c#, razor

Given the following text

```
we’ve attached a worksheet we’ve
```

I've noticed that if this fragment is a web page it renders like this

[image]

in Chrome and Edge, but if I email it through Exchange then it comes across just fine. How might I prevent this from happening so that I can reuse the text in both a webpage and email?

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: Use the ASCII apostrophe.

Comment: What web frameworks are you using and are you manually setting the charset to ascii? Most browser support html in unicode out of the box. Also where are you getting the string from?